# I need to run a report from 1/1/17 - YTD automatically

Tags: custom-reports

How do I run a report YTD (year to date) automatically. I.e. I would like it so that when I click on a report it automatically selects 1/1/17 and today in the date ranges?

Comment: please specify your requirement clearly.